# What's the name of the cohomology class associated to a projective representation?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, terminology, group-cohomology

Suppose $\rho : G \to PGL_n(k)$ is a projective representation of a group $G$ over a field $k$. It's classical that the obstruction to lifting this to a linear representation $G \to GL_n(k)$ is a cohomology class $[c] \in H^2(G, k^{\times})$.

> **Question:** What's the name of this cohomology class?

It's tempting to call it the **Schur class**, but googling this name only produced a single paper from 1974 which used it in connection with projective representations. I haven't been able to find any other name in common use. If no one suggests a better name, that's the one I'll go with.

Comment: I think "the cohomology class associated with the projective representation" is a name that's in fairly common use.

Comment: So "Schur class" is much shorter... of course, it depends if you have to use it 3 times or 50 times in a single paper...

Comment: This kind of obstruction is called Mackey obstruction.  By abuse of language we could call this cohomology class "the" Mackey obstruction.